# Picasso not loading images on first app start

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, google-maps-markers, picasso

I have `Activity` with `GoogleMap` and I send request to server, parse JSON response and add `Markers`, using Picasso for loading icons.

**PROBLEM**

The problem is next: when I close app and open It again, data loads as well (urls also loading well), `Markers` are added on `GoogleMap`, but they have default icons, Picasso doesn't load new icons (onBitmapLoaded() not called). When I finish `Activity` and start it again (without app closing), new markers' icons loads as well.

My implementation of Picasso Target:

```
public class PicassoMarker implements Target {
    private static final String TAG = "PicassoMarker";
    private Marker marker;
    private LoadingCallBacks loadingCallBacks;

    public PicassoMarker(Marker marker) {
        this.marker = marker;
    }

    public PicassoMarker(Marker marker, LoadingCallBacks loadingCallBacks) {
        this.marker = marker;
        this.loadingCallBacks = loadingCallBacks;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return marker.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof PicassoMarker) {
            Marker marker = ((PicassoMarker) o).marker;
            return this.marker.equals(marker);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
        Log.d(TAG, "onBitmapLoaded() -> " +
                "\nBitmap:" +
                "\n\twidth: " + bitmap.getWidth() +
                "\n\theight: " + bitmap.getHeight() /*+
                "\nCanvas:" +
                "\n\twidth: " + resultBitmap.getWidth() +
                "\n\theight: " + resultBitmap.getHeight()*/
        );

        if (loadingCallBacks != null) {
            loadingCallBacks.onLoaded(bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onBitmapFailed()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepareLoad()");
    }

    public void setLoadingCallBacks(LoadingCallBacks loadingCallBacks) {
        this.loadingCallBacks = loadingCallBacks;
    }

    public interface LoadingCallBacks {
        void onLoaded(Bitmap bitmap);
    }
}
```

And my `AsyncTask` for sending request and adding `Markers`:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<MarkerDataModel>>() {
            private ArrayList<MarkerDataModel> markerDataModels = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<MarkerDataModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
                // Parsing JSON ...

                return markerDataModels;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MarkerDataModel> markerDataModels) {
                if (markerDataModels != null && markerDataModels.size() != 0) {
                    MarkerDataModel markerDataModel;

                    for (int i = 0; i < markerDataModels.size(); i++) {
                        markerDataModel = markerDataModels.get(i);

                        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(markerDataModel.getLat(), markerDataModel.getLng()))
                                .title(markerDataModel.getLabel()));

                        PicassoMarker picassoMarker picassoMarker = new PicassoMarker(marker);
                        Picasso.
                                with(activityContext)
                                .load(markerDataModel.getIcon())
                                //.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                                //.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                                .into(picassoMarker);
                    }
                }
            }
        }.execute("http://example.com");
```

Comment: Could you try keeping a strong reference to your `PicassoMarker` - `Picasso` itself will keep only a `WeakReference` and thus will not prevent the `PicassoMarker` from being garbage collected. I am not sure this explains why you get the markers the second time but it is something to keep in mind - it may be the case that the first time Picasso is too slow because it loads the icons from the network/disc (?) but is fast enough the second time when the icon is already in the cache.

Comment: @david.mihola, Thank you for reply! Notice, I keep strong reference. I tried to prevent cache check, when icons are loading from URL, Picasso loaded them as well, but only second time. My solution for this problem is Glide. Glide loads icons great after first activity start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I've solved problem, using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Here is example code for loading `Markers'` data from network and setting new icons using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<MarkerDataModel>>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<MarkerDataModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
                ArrayList<MarkerDataModel> markerDataModels = new ArrayList<>();

                Send request and parse response...

                return markerDataModels;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MarkerDataModel> markerDataModels) {
                if (markerDataModels != null && markerDataModels.size() != 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < markerDataModels.size(); i++) {
                        MarkerDataModel markerDataModel = markerDataModels.get(i);

                        final Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(markerDataModel.getLat(), markerDataModel.getLng()))
                                .title(markerDataModel.getLabel()));

            // Getting icon's URL from DataModel and loading icon
            Glide
                .with(activityContext)
                .load(markerDataModel.getIcon())
                .asBitmap()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    // Setting new icon for Marker
                    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resource));
                }
                });
                    }
                }
            }
        }.execute(...);
```

And `MarkerDataModel` is simple class for storing `Marker's` data:

```
public class MarkerDataModel {

    public MarkerDataModel() {
    }

    private final String TAG = "MarkerDataModel";

    public static final int TYPE_PRIMARY = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_PEOPLE = 2;

    private int type;
    private int id;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    private Marker marker;

    /**
     * TYPE_PRIMARY
     **/
    private String icon;
    private String label;
    private String nameShort;
    private String nameFull;
    private String phone;
    private String information;
    private String website;
    private String sliderImages;

    /**
     * TYPE_PEOPLE
     **/
    private String photoUrl;
    private String uniqueId;
    private String registerTime;

    public MarkerDataModel(int type,
                           int id,
                           double lat,
                           double lng,
                           String icon,
                           String label,
                           String nameShort,
                           String nameFull,
                           String phone,
                           String information,
                           String website,
                           String sliderImages) {

        this.type = type;
        this.id = id;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.label = label;
        this.nameShort = nameShort;
        this.nameFull = nameFull;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.information = information;
        this.website = website;
        this.sliderImages = sliderImages;
    }

    public MarkerDataModel(int type,
                           int id,
                           double lat,
                           double lng,
                           String photoUrl,
                           String uniqueId,
                           String registerTime) {
        this.type = type;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
        this.registerTime = registerTime;
    }

    /**
     * Getters
     */

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Nullable
    public Marker getMarker() {
        return marker;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    /**
     * TYPE_PRIMARY
     **/

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public String getInformation() {
        return information;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public String getNameFull() {
        return nameFull;
    }

    public String getNameShort() {
        return nameShort;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getSliderImages() {
        return sliderImages;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }


    /**
     * TYPE_PEOPLE
     **/
    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public String getRegisterTime() {
        return registerTime;
    }


    @Nullable
    public LatLng getLatLng() {
        try {
            return new LatLng(lat, lng);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getLatLng() -> ", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Setters
     */

    public void setMarker(Marker marker) {
        this.marker = marker;
    }
}
```

**BENEFITS**

Switching between `TYPE_PRIMARY` and `TYPE_PEOPLE` you can catch type of clicked `Marker` like this:

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        MarkerDataModel markerDataModel = markerAllHashMap.get(marker);
        int type;

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "onMarkerClick() -> " + markerDataModel.getType());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onMarkerClick() -> ", ex);
        }

        try {
            type = markerDataModel.getType();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            type = -1;
        }

        switch (type) {
            case MarkerDataModel.TYPE_PRIMARY: {
                // Do something for TYPE_PRIMARY Marker
                break;
            }
            case MarkerDataModel.TYPE_PEOPLE: {
                // Do something for TYPE_PEOPLE Marker (e.g. show user's info)
                break;
            }
            default: {
                // Type == -1
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Animate to center
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(marker.getPosition())
                .zoom(18)
                .build()));

        return true;
    }
});
```